# Annihilating ideal of $Z_8$, $A(Z_8)$ is an ideal of ring $Z_8$. The collection of ideals of a ring is again an ideal of that ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

A nonzero ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is called an annihilating ideal if there exists a nonzero ideal $J$ such that $IJ = (0)$.
$A(Z_8) = \left\{(0), (2), (4), (6)\right\}$. 
By definition of ideal, $A(Z_8)$ is contained in the commutative ring $Z_8$ and it also satisfy the property of ideal (i.e.,) $A(Z_8)$ is closed under addition. 
Therefore I am thinking $A(Z_8)$ is an ideal of the ring $Z_8$. 
Is it true or not? $A(Z_8)$ is the collection of annihilating ideals of $Z_8$. I want to know whether $A(Z_8)$ is an ideal of $Z_8$ or not.

Comment: What exactly do you denote $A(\mathbf Z_8)$?

Comment: $A(Z_8)$ is nothing but annihilating ideal of $Z_8$

Comment: In which ring? $\mathbf Z$?

Comment: commutative ring with identity